# How to remove all rows from dataframe if count of simillar `person_id` values are not `== 2`

Tags: r

I need remove all rows from dataframe if count of simillar `person_id` values are not `== 2`. For example:

```
a1 <- data.frame(person_id = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(person_id = 2:6, b=letters[6:10])
data = rbind(a1, a2)

   person_id b
1          1 a
2          2 b
3          3 c
4          4 d
5          5 e
6          2 f
7          3 g
8          4 h
9          5 i
10         6 j
```

Row 1 and 10 must be removed, because `person_id==1` and `person_id==6` have only 1 record. For example `person_id==2` have 2 rows.

How can I get new dataset with only rows where count of rows with `person_id` values are `== 2` (and in future 3 or 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
subset(
  data, 
  ave(person_id, person_id, FUN = length) == 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the rows where count of person_id isn't equal to 2:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  filter(n() == 2)

  person_id b    
      <int> <chr>
1         2 b    
2         3 c    
3         4 d    
4         5 e    
5         2 f    
6         3 g    
7         4 h    
8         5 i
```